# The button clicked by code jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, click

Is there any function of `Javascript` or `Jquery` to make a button clicked by code?
I already search on the internet but didn't see the answer for this.
Thanks so much!

Comment: have u heared about trigger in jquery. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$("#yourButtonElement").click();
```

#### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeZTx/)

Note this is also possible in native JavaScript without jQuery

#### [Native JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvB8r/)

Comment: oh, thanks, I saw that before but I think it just for add an event for element. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3gCR3/) if you click button 2 it'll trigger click event for button 1 also.